# How to retrieve Scheduled Post in Wordpress REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, api, wordpress-rest-api

I've spent a lot of time to find the right solution for this.
The best information I could find so far is from here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/191258/return-scheduled-posts-with-wp-rest-api

I am using Jetpack for the REST API and this how it looks like for published posts:
https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1.1/sites/MYDOMAIN.com/posts/

Apparently you need to be logged in as a user that has the edit_posts capability. With that capability, you also get access to the private query vars, including post_status.

But the post doesn't explain how to include a logged in user in the REST API call so that I can get scheduled/future posts.

Thanks

Comment: Read this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37267/does-wordpress-provide-an-api-for-scheduling-posts

Comment: @BharatDangar this is just for actually creating the posts to be scheduled? not to get a list of all posts including those?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but you can set the status to future to get scheduled posts.

https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?status=future

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).